# potentialStarter not found

Tags: activiti, flowable

I read the document [Activiti UserGuide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_getting_started)

In chapter 8.8. Process Initiation Authorization

```
List<Group> authorizedGroups =  identityService().createGroupQuery().potentialStarter("processDefinitionId").list();
```

but In Activiti 7.0, GroupQuery does not have the method potentialStarter, how can I query processdefinition initiated by some groups?

Answer (score 0):

The user guide that you are looking at is for Activiti 6, not 7. Activiti 7 is going to be Beta1 very soon, and there will be separate guides for that version, due the fact that we are aiming for a Cloud Native version of Activiti.